# OpenOffice Automation delphi

Tags: delphi, automation, wrapper, openoffice.org

We want to automate OpenOffice, When i search on internet couldnot find a end-to-end help for that and delphi examples are too less. Our intention is to insert document variables and replace the document variable with there values and copying paragraphs etc.

Can any one help me to find an end-to-end help or a pas file like word2000.pas where i can find all the word routines.

Thanks,
Basil

Comment: OpenOffice has python bindings for automation, so you probably won't find anything on delphi.

Comment: @Spencer, your comment suggests that the existence of Python bindings somehow precludes the existence of Delphi bindings. How do you figure? If there are C bindings, Delphi can use them with minimal effort. Surely there are projects that provide Python and C bindings, so why couldn't there be projects that provide Python and Delphi bindings?

Comment: @RobKennedy My apologies, I simply meant that python bindings come prebuilt. [Looking at the docs](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/AdvUNO/Implementing_UNO_Language_Bindings) it is apparent that OpenOffice includes the ability to bind other languages as well. However, the question seemed to indicate that they wanted to use *native delphi* code, rather than hooking to a *C library*, which is what the other half of my statement referred to.

Comment: Latest version 1.3 of OOo by Bernard Marcelly is here now:

http://bernard.marcelly.perso.sfr.fr/index2.html

Answer (score 3):

I do use OpenOffice-Automation with Delphi a lot and I think there is no "wrapper" with higher functionality for Delphi.

There is a Delphi OO Project on SourceForge with helpers and examples as a starting point: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ooomacros/files/Delphi%20OOo/Version%201.2/Delphi_OOo_v12en.zip/download

Then you have to study the UNO-API and use COM to call the UNO functions.

Comment: The link with the example you've provided is totally out of date. There were major changes since OOo 2.x.x till the current one.

Comment: My appologies. I thought this version was the newest one, sorry. (however, works good with OO 3.2) Can you tell me where the newest version can be found? Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of updated information here:
https://www.freepascal.org/~michael/articles/openoffice1/openoffice.pdf